# How to performantly query using a function applied to an MySQL auto-increment column?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, index

I have a users table in MySQL 8 with an auto-increment id as primary key: `CREATE TABLE users (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, primary key (id) )`.

I have a use case for sorting the users into 1000 randomly distributed groups. I'd like to do it by modulo against id (for example, `select * where id mod 1000 = 0` is group 0, `select * where id mod 1000 = 1` is group 1, etc.) because then a user's group can be trivially calculated on the client or anywhere else from their id. (I realize that using PKs in the application is controversial -- perhaps this question is an example of why -- but that ship sailed long ago.)

But this is not performant enough: the query cannot use the index on id, and with the number of rows in this table (which is continually growing), selecting users in a group (a requirement of the use case) takes several seconds even on a beefy server. I need <=1s query time.

I looked into generated columns, but they cannot use an auto-increment column as a base column. Because functional indexes use generated columns under the hood, they are out, too. A view won't help, either. What other options are there?

Comment: *I have a use case for sorting the users into 1000 randomly distributed groups. I'd like to do it by modulo against id* Is this frequently performed operation? if so then you may add virtual generated column with group number and create an index by it.

Comment: "That ship has sailed" is a surrender to the [sunk cost fallacy](https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/the-sunk-cost-fallacy/).

Answer (score 1):

`where id mod 1000` is equivalent to applying a function to the column `id`.  Such is not "sargable", hence the execution will simply scan the entire table.  Changing the "1000" will not change the speed of the scan, but will change the speed of the reply -- simply because of the number of rows delivered.

If your goal is efficient fetching of several "random" rows, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

If there is a "group_number" that is derived from `id`, then `SELECT ... WHERE group_number = 123` may be very efficient if you also have `INDEX(group_number)`.  Either add another column for that and populate it.  Or consider a "generated" column.

Avoid the `REPLACE` statement; it is essentially `DELETE` + `INSERT` -- and the 'mod' will change.